# How to pass the exception in the loop?

Tags: python, loops, try-catch, except

I'm crawling some financial statement from 'naver'. In my code list(kospi_list),
an incorrect code exists. So, I made an exception to avoid it. However it doesn't work well.

Once the program notice the incorrect code, it process the program as an exception until the end. I just want to continue the loop.

Could you help me?
Thanks in advance.

```
def connect(self):
    for code in self.kospi_list:
        url = "https://companyinfo.stock.naver.com/v1/company/c1010001.aspx?cmp_cd=%s&cn=" % code

        try:
            self.driver.get(url)
            html = self.driver.page_source
            self.soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

        except:
            pass
        else:
            name = self.get_name()
            result = self.loop()
            if result is not None:
                self.save_sql(result, name)

            print(result)

    self.driver.close()
```

Comment: `except: continue`?

Comment: also code under `except` does not need `else`, there's no `if` statement to begin with.

Comment: In your `except:` block, try adding `traceback.clear_frames(sys.exc_info()[2])`. Of course, you will need to import `traceback`.